# store password securely for runtime in C

Tags: c, email, client, password-protection, password-encryption

I am currently writing a mail client in C. But I have a question about storing the password.

I just want to store it as long as the program runs. 
As a password is a "string" I could store it in a char array, which gets overwritten shortly before the program ends. But this would be relatively insecure.

How can I securely store a password just during the program's runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite right to avoid holding the password in cleartext.

If you *have* to retain the password (for instance, you need to send it to the server periodically), it's best to keep it in an encrypted form. Which encrypted form is up to you. This makes it harder for someone doing memory profiling on the program to see the password. (Harder, not impossible; if you have to send the password to a server, and someone has physical access to the machine to do memory profiling, all you can do is make it difficult.)

When using it, you'd do this:

- Allocate a temporary array
- Decrypt to an array
- Use the array (for instance, to send the password to the server)
- Overwrite the array
- Release the array

If you want to be ***really*** paranoid, when overwriting the array, do several items in sequence, for instance (this is just an example):

- All zeros
- All ones
- Choose a random byte value
- Fill the array with that byte value
- Fill again with the value bitshifted once
- Fill again with the value bitshifted again
- Fill again with the value bitshifted a third time
- Fill again with the value bitshifted a fourth time
- Fill again with the value bitshifted a fifth time
- Fill again with the value bitshifted a sixth time
- Fill again with the value bitshifted a seventh time
- All ones
- All zeros

...as apparently some researchers have been able, on occasion, to retrieve an echo of previous data through forensic analysis of the memory cells in RAM. But I think this falls in the category of paranoia. (But it's cheap to do. ;-) )

Comment: Hi,thanks for your fast anwser, but I know have a second question. When I encrypt my password and save this in the array, my program has to decrypt it again, so when an "attacker" knw the code wouldn't it be easy for him to decrypt the encrypted password saved in the array? Could you give me a tip or link for further reading?

Comment: @user3852496: Indeed they would, but now instead of just looking at the memory of the program and running pattern matches against it looking for things likely to be passwords, they have to find where you're doing the decryption. As I said, you *can't* make it impossible for someone who has full power over the machine to get the information, all you can do is make it much harder. (Sorry, I don't happen to have any specific links.)

Comment: Thanks again, do you have any adive for me how to avoid that pattern matches find my password array or where I should do the decryotion or for my en- and decryption function? :-)

Comment: @user3852496: I'm afraid not. Not my area of expertise.